# How to use Restkit 0.10.X to POST JSON and map response

Tags: ios, post, restkit

When I make a Get Like this

```
//Query Parameters for Login: Email and Password
NSDictionary *queryParams;
queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: email,@"email",password,@"password", nil];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

//Pointing to the login query in the server
RKURL *URL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[objectManager baseURL] resourcePath:@"/default/api/login.json" queryParameters:queryParams];
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", [URL resourcePath], [URL query]] delegate:self];
```

And Use a Mapping like this:

```
//Creamos un mapeo para el Login mapping
RKObjectMapping *sessionMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[UrSession class]];
[sessionMapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:@"uid", @"uid", @"token", @"token", nil];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:sessionMapping forKeyPath:@"result"];
```

Everything is Ok, the response from the server is mapped to my Object UrSession.

But now we need to change the client because the server needs a POST and not a GET for the login. 
Ok, then this is my Code:

```
RKClient *myClient = [RKClient sharedClient];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//User and password params
[params setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
[params setObject:email forKey:@"email"];


//Parsing rpcData to JSON!
id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *json = [parser stringFromObject:params error:&error];

//If no error we send the post, voila!
if (!error){
    [myClient post:@"/default/api/loginPost.json" params:[RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON] delegate:self];
}
```

Ok,until here everything is OK. 
The server response to my POST but my code doesn't map this response!!.. Why?. I know I'm lossing something, but I can not understand why with the GET Restkit Map the JSON from the server, but with the GET it doesn't.

I'm a little desperate because I can't find a solution that works with my code.

Thank you for your help.

---

Finally this is the Code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *paramsDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//User and password params
[paramsDic setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
[paramsDic setObject:email forKey:@"email"];

//Parsing to JSON
id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *json = [parser stringFromObject:paramsDic error:&error];
RKParams *params = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"loginPost.json" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader * loader)
 {
     loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
     loader.params = params;
     loader.delegate = self;
  }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a request using RKClient the response won't be mapped to an object. You must user RKObjectManager for mapping.

You can make a POST request with method loadObjectAtResourcePath by using blocks like this:

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/path" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader * loader)
  {
                loader.method = RKRequestMethodPost;
                loader.params = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
                loader.delegate = self;
  }];
```

The response will be mapped to your object.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, you saved my life :) . I've post the code, maybe can be useful for others with the same problem.